# log4j with Tomcat6

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j, web-applications, tomcat6

I have a peculiar problem with Log4j. We are deploying on Weblogic 10 using `log4j.xml`. That works fine. We figured a way to run Tomcat 6 in such a way that we can develop on this platform and deploy on Weblogic 10.

I have figured out how to make `log4j.properies` work with Tomcat 6 with additional JArs that use the JULI logging mechanism in Tomcat 6. Unfortunately, my `log4j.xml` (that works with Weblogic) fails to work with Tomcat 6. So I am forced to use `log4j.properties`.

I have not been able to figure out how to indicate application class hierarchies in `log4j.properties`.
So my question is how does on convert the following `log4j.xml` entries to `log4j.properties`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

<appender name="vccashib" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <param name="File" value="vccashib_10.log"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %t %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <logger name="org.hibernate">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="vccashib" />
  </logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

So let us say I was to write a logger that captures logs for classes in my `com.abc.xyz` hierarchy. How do I indicate that in `log4j.properties`? (I have taken care of a other values, such as type of appenders, DatePattern, ConversionPattern, FileName, layout etc.)

Please note, I have sent you the only problem-specific code.

Alternatively, if you know the answer on how to make `log4j.xml` that is part of my war archive with Tomcat 6 (JULI jars are in place and work well with `log4j.properties`), please let me know

Please help.

Suhaas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on your question. I've deployed `log4j` on tomcat 6 with no problems (can you post the specific problems you're having with your xml config?). I'm not sure what you mean by  "I have figured out how to make `log4j.properies` work with Tomcat 6 with additional jars that use the JULI logging mechanism in Tomcat 6").

- is the config in the proper location?
- are some of your jars being loaded
  from the global tomcat
  (`$TOMCAT_HOME/lib`) directory? If so
  the library might be looking for the
  config from the global directory,
  rather than from your webapp.

If you're just talking about how to manage separate class hierarchies in your `log4j` config, it's something like :

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO,stdout

#e.g. not interested in most stripes or spring warnings
log4j.logger.net.sourceforge.stripes=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.springframework=ERROR

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-d %-5p [%t] %c{1} %3x - 
%m%n

#This creates the separate log "Foo" at DEBUG level. Everythign within 
#the "com.foo" package will
# get logged here
log4j.category.com.foo=DEBUG,Foo
log4j.appender.Foo=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Foo.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Foo.layout.ConversionPattern=%-d %-5p [%t] %c{1} %3x - %m%n
log4j.appender.DetailLogFile.File=foo.log
#this is the important line - if this isn't here the stuff in
#com.foo package will show up in both logs.
log4j.additivity.com.foo=false
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using tomcat6 with `log4j`. We followed the [following manual](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html) to install `log4j` in the tomcat - it is more complicated than on the old versions (4.1-5.5).
I believe you should put your `log4j.xml` under the `WEB-INF/classes` directory in your war.

An additional approach is to use the spring framework for this - see [Log4jConfigListener's API](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jConfigListener.html)

Answer (score 0):

IT appears to me that there was no problem with creation of logs even with log4j.xml

I did use http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html to create logging mechanism as suggested.

Interestingly the logs were being created in the bin directory of Tomcat 6 !!! It is something to do with the current working directory and in my case it seems to be the bin directory as per some Catalina setting

Answer (score 0):

According to http://boncey.org/2006_7_25_log4j_with_xml_configuration

1. `export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.xml"` (I suppose to force it to look for `.xml` rather than `.properties`)
2. put `log4j.xml` file into `WEB-INF/classes`

I had a similar problem and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Few simple steps described below will help you to set up web application's log4j to be initialized:

1) copy `log4j.xml` to your `(TOMCAT_HOME)/CATALINA_HOME/conf` directory. The `log4j.xml` of my application looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration>
 <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
   <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE}
      %5p %c{1}:%L -Preetam %m%n"/>

        </layout>
     </appender>
       <root>
        <!--   <priority value="info"></priority> -->
               <priority value="debug"></priority>
          <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
        </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

2) stop the tomcat

```
tomcat6 stop /var/tmp/tomcat-20120622.log (use your application specific stop.sh script)
```

3) In `(TOMCAT_HOME)/CATALINA_HOME/conf` directory, you will have the `tomcat6.conf` file. Edit the file as described below. If there is no `CATALINA_OPTS` in the `tomcat6.conf`, create one.

```
# Settings for the CATALINA_OPTS to pick web application's log4j.xml from the specified location
CATALINA_OPTS="${CATALINA_OPTS}-Dlog4j.debug - Dlog4j.configuration=file:${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/log4j.xml"
```

4) Start the tomcat with your application specific `startup.sh` script.

5) Thats it, you are all done. Check the log to see if the tomcat is reading the `log4j.xml` specified by you in `tomcat6.conf`.

`tail -f /var/tmp/tomcat-20120622.log`

```
Jun 22, 2012 3:28:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
Jun 22, 2012 3:28:35 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jun 22, 2012 3:28:35 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Jun 22, 2012 3:28:35 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/12  config=null
Jun 22, 2012 3:28:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 547 ms
log4j: Using URL [file:/opt/otccalypso/guiadmd01/tomcat6/conf/log4j.xml] for automatic    log4j configuration.
log4j: Preferred configurator class: org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator
log4j: System property is :null
log4j: Standard DocumentBuilderFactory search succeded.
log4j: DocumentBuilderFactory is: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
log4j: debug attribute= "null".
log4j: Ignoring debug attribute.
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Level value for root is  [debug].
log4j: root level set to DEBUG
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ABSOLUTE}        %5p %c{1}:%L -Preetam %m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [stdout] to category [root].
```

Comment: Important to notice the log:                                    INFO: Server startup in 547 ms
log4j: Using URL [file:/opt/otccalypso/guiadmd01/tomcat6/conf/log4j.xml] for automatic log4j configuration.